# Drill into xml file for data with colon in name

Tags: xml, powershell, prop-drilling

I'm trying to do a script to compare gpo's from a list generated with "Get-GPOReport -All -ReportType csv".[image: XML file] I'm running into issues because i dont know how to drill into the q3:policy data.

[image: Pulling data with this]

I'm pulling data from other sections of xml but under Extension Data theres <q3:Policy> naming convention with the colon with is stopping my drilling.

Yes I've done Get-Member and gone through the properties. The best I can get is into the extension. [image: deepest I can get so far]

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of code - post the code as text instead. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3156906 for why...